# WCF Rest Service Download File "Semaphore Exception"

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding, wcf-rest

I am facing an issue with download a file from server with WCF rest serice. On localhost everything is working fine, but when i expose the api from static ip then remote computer is not able to download the large file (500Mb).

Below is my test scenario so far:

1. Using webHttpBinding.
2. With transferMode = "buffered", the file is transferring but having exception of byteArraylength.
3. With transferMode = "streamed", the file is start download at remote browser, but stop inbetween ans server side there is an exception of "Semaphore timeout period expired".

Service contract

```
<ServiceContract>
Public Interface IService   
    <OperationContract()>
    <WebGet(UriTemplate:="File/{Param}", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)>
    Function FileDownloadRequest(Param As String) As Stream
End Interface

<ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode:=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, UseSynchronizationContext:=False)>
Public Class RequestHandler
    Implements IService

Private Function FileDownloadRequest(Param As String) As Stream Implements IService.FileDownloadRequest
        Dim _FileName As String = RootFolder & "\" & Param
        Try
            ReqLogs.Add("<<-- Download request recieved for " & _FileName)
            '
            'Header Set For CORS
            '
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")            
            If File.Exists(_FileName) Then
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers("Content-Disposition") = "attachment; filename=" + "Report Data.csv"
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = Net.HttpStatusCode.OK

                Dim _FStream As New FileStream(_FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentLength = _FStream.Length
                ReqLogs.Add("<<-- Download processing..... ++ " & _FStream.Length.ToString)
                Return _FStream
            Else
                ReqLogs.Add("---- File not found to download !!!")
                Throw New Exception("File not found to download")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ReqLogs.Add("Download event error: " & ex.Message)
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Have you tried adding this parameter to your config file : `maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864"` and don't specify a value for transferMode.

Comment: Hi, this parameter i have tried already with 2147483647. Not specifying anything to transferMode will be buffered by default.

Comment: Have you tested the maximum file transfer capacity when the program is running properly.

Comment: How to test that? can you please suggest on it.

Comment: Increase the size of the transfer file after the normal operation of the program until the error, the file size before the error is basically the maximum value of the transfer file.

Comment: It is random, I can transfer 46Mb sometimes and on the other hand its stops at 4Mb or below. It is so random, maximum i did so far is 67Mb. But still it is not fixed, it is keep changing on each request.

Comment: Is there any progress so far?

Comment: Sorry for a late reply, But while testing it on actual server instead of laptop, Problem got solved, it never appeared again.